# Changing specific numeric values in an excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to color, for example, the 1s and 0s in a string such as "1001001001" as two different colors using a VBA Macro. Is this possible?
Here is my attempted code

```
Sub changeTextColor()

     Green = RGB(0, 255, 0)
     Red = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     Black = RGB(0, 0, 0)

     'Select cell
     Range("H2").Select

     For x = 1 To 10
         If ActiveCell.Value = "1" Then

            'Change the text color if "1"

             ActiveCell.Font.Color = Green   

         ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "0" Then

             'Change the text color if "0"

             ActiveCell.Font.Color = Red

         End If

         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Please post code that you have tried. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: (Please instead edit that into your OP, it's hard to read in a comment)

Comment: Added, my apologies

Comment: You're testing the entire cell, not each character. Edit: you want `.characters`.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Characters([start], [length]).Font.Color = Red` and test each character using `Mid(ActiveCell.Value, x,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub changeTextColor()

    Dim v, s, clr, rng, x

    Set rng = Range("H2")


    Do While rng.Value <> ""
        v = rng.Value
        For x = 1 To Len(v)

            Select Case Mid(v, x, 1)
               Case "1": clr = vbGreen
               Case "0": clr = vbRed
               Case Else: clr = vbBlack
            End Select

            rng.Characters(x, 1).Font.Color = clr

        Next x

        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this changes all of the characters to green instead of only the 1's?

Comment: My bad - I edited after posting and didn't re-test.  Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. Whats happening now is the code is taking the first occurrence of the digit, for example, if it is 10101, it will see the first 1 and change it to green, but it also changes every following 0 to green as well

Comment: My apologies, works perfectly, thank you so much for your help!